# Anyone knows the probability density which includes $\exp(-x^4)$

Tags: probability

I am curious about the density which contains something like $\exp(-x^4)$. Anyone can provide the name and some properties?

Comment: Your question seems quite vague, and I don't really know what you are asking for to be honest. Could you clarify it and explain what you mean?

Comment: At the moment, you ***do not*** have a probability density. Or in other words, we need more info.

Comment: Search through [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) and see what you can find.

Comment: Two families of distributions you could look up (say on Wikipedia) are the Weibull distribution and the generalized normal distribution.

Comment: This question is not unclear.  Notice that there is a posted answer (although it doesn't say much).  Possibly there is not much to say. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create your own pdf 
$$
f(x)={\exp(-x^4)\over c}\quad\forall\quad x\in\mathbb R
$$
where $$
c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^4)\,dx
$$
Convergence of $c$ is easily provable but this distribution would not be standard (most likely).

Comment: and not hard to show that $\displaystyle c = \frac {1} {2} \Gamma\left(\frac {1} {4}\right)$